# Spacing not equal within bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a weird problem with a bootstrap grid. The code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                       <img src="<?PHP echo _ROOT;?>/public/images/startpage/customer_large.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quote_right col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-0">
                        <p class="text-center">
                            ‹‹Das Geheimnis des Erfolgs ist, den Standpunkt des anderen zu verstehen.››
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <span class="speaker">Henry Ford</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

On the webpage the content is displayed:
[image]

So there are two things:

1. Why is the last div container "wider" than the other? The other boxes are images with the img-responsive class.
2. How to make the last div the same height as the one on the left?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question, there are already many solutions available on Stackoverflow
So, three solution that I know work...

**Solution 1** using negative margins (doesn't break responsiveness)

```
    .row{
        overflow: hidden; 
    }
```

```
[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
</pre>
```

**Solution 2** using table

```
    .row {
        display: table;
    }
```

`[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
</pre>`

**Solution 3** using flex added August 2015.(that I really don't prefer) 
    
    .row {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display:         flex;
    }
    
Visit this link for the elaborated answer. 
[How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: thanks this has led me in the right direction. Greetings